# BeagleBone Black reboots periodically

Tags: power, reset, beaglebone-black, debian

My BeagleBone Black reboots periodically after some random time (> 5hours)? I am totally stucked with ideas, I have my app working for that some random time and system gets reset. BBB works on Debian Linux. Is there any solution for this, whether someone was in the same situation?

Comment: Is you power supply up to the sak, with ample margin? Could there be a brown-out in your mains power?

Comment: Is it resetting or rebooting gracefully? if its the latter it should indicate the reason in the logs.

Comment: It reboots after a few hours. Nothing weird in logs.

Comment: And memory stats? CPUclock stats? Does it reboot without the application running? `cpufreq-info` and `free`

Comment: verify your PWRONRSTn pin in yout CPU AM335x, as said in the datasheet of the CPU, this pin allows to configure the sysboot mode of your BBB. See §6.1.2 from the datasheet of the processor AM335x: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am3358.pdf

Comment: Does 'Random Time' mean it's a different interval each time or is it a repeatable interval?

Comment: Have you tried `last reboot`?

Comment: what are the thermals on your board? you can get the CPU temperature using [this script](http://inspire.logicsupply.com/2014/12/beaglebone-cpu-temperature-monitor.html) if you see that the heat is causing the reboots, try using some form of [heat sinking](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1041)

Comment: Do you have a LCD display, if so what type of display to you have. Do you power the BBB with USB connector or 5V barrel connector? What type of application are you running, graphical or command level. I suggest that you look at [Can not boot BeagleBone Black with 4D LCD touch screen using pre-built Android images](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/2458/110) If you could add some hw and sw details to the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen similar issues with the beaglebone black. Below was my hardware and Software configuration.

- **Hardware:** Beaglebone Black A5C, 4D System LCD Display, USB cable, old 5V 0.8A cell phone charger re-purposed.
- **Software:** Angstrom with Embedded QT or Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean).  Ubuntu base host system

I found that the System was resetting when the system was powered using 5V USB power. The current capacity with 5V USB I believe is 500mA. The problem was common when running an Android Application. Also similar issues were occasionally observed when running Embedded QT base applications.

**Solution:** Use a 5V external power supply with current capacity of 1A or 2A. In my case for small application the 5V 0.8A supply worked find. If I load the system I had to use the 5V USB power. I recommend using the 1A or 2A power supply.

**External Power Supply**

[image: External Power Supply]

<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

Hope this solves your problem.

---

**References:**

- [Can not boot BeagleBone Black with 4D LCD touch screen using pre-built Android images](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/2458/110)
- [Boot android (TI-JB) on beaglebone black from SD card](http://forum.4dsystems.com.au/forum/forum-aa/4d-systems-hardware/beaglebone-display-modules-and-capes/4498-boot-android-ti-jb-on-beaglebone-black-from-sd-card)
- [4D 4.3” LCD CAPE Beagle Bone Black 4.3” LCD CAPE](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/productpages/4DCAPE-43/downloads/4DCAPE-43(T)_datasheet_R_1_9.pdf)
- [BeagleBone Black Accessories](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBone_Black_Accessories)

Answer (score 2):

There might be the possibility your program is having a memory leak over time. This normally would cause a system to slow down but it might make it crash periodically. My biggest bet however would be that the 512MB of DDR3 RAM of the BBB might have some fault. You could run a memory test to verify for this... check for a program called memtest86+ for Debian, this should at least indicate if the problem is RAM related.

Comment: Note that memtest86 won't work - this is ARM.